Azure Service Bus consumers rebalancing similar to Kafka consumer group rebalancing
I have previous experience with Kafka and I am relatively new to Azure Service Bus. Taking into account similarities between Kafka partitions and Azure Service Bus sessions, I am wondering if it's possible in a case of a Service Bus consumer scaling to multiple instances, to have similar kind of rebalancing automatically in a way Kafka does it. With Kafka we don't need to worry about optimal rebalancing between consumers and partitions in situations when our consumer scales up and down horizontally.
So far, I haven't been able to find similar capability of Azure Service Bus. Let's say there are 3 sessions on a Service Bus subscription and there is one consumer. That single consumer locks all 3 sessions and at some point the consumer is scaled from 1 instance to 3. According to my (at this moment limited) understanding of Azure Service Bus, the first instance will continue to hold the locks on all 3 sessions and other 2 consumer instances would sit idle until messages stop to arrive in these sessions and the first instance release the locks. Only then it's possible for other 2 consumer instances to lock these sessions.
This seems impractical because we usually scale at a moment of high load when messages land on the topic massively. And because messages come to the topic actively, the first consumer instance won't release these locks? And then there is no benefit from horizontal scaling of the consumer container.
Please help, or let me know if I misunderstood something.

A client will only process a single session in Service Bus at a time. Once the session is empty, you switch to the next session. As such, when more clients are initialized, they will request for the next available session and start processing their corresponding sessions. For more details, I would recommend reading through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions, including the linked code samples.

It is not true that a single client can only process a single session at time. By default, it can process 8 sessions in parallel, and that number can be configured by setting maxConcurrentSessions explicitly.
I still want all the messages on the topic to be processed even if I have a single consumer. I don't want some of the sessions to stay unprocessed if my consumer doesn't scale. But if I have 10 sessions and 1 consumer that holds a lock on 3 sessions with constant messages income, that consumer won't have an opportunity to process other sessions at all. That's not the case with Kafka.

Also with Service Bus when a single consumer finishes processing all messages on the current set of sessions, it doesn't release the locks on those sessions (and moves to other sessions) immediately. The property sessionIdleTimeout, which is 60 seconds by default, will make a consumer to wait for that period of time on the current sessions, waiting for potential new messages, and only if no messages come during that time interval, it will jump to other sessions. And if the listener holds a lock on all existing sessions on the subscription, other listeners can not process messages effectively.

Okay, some clarification needed, as it seems I did not describe myself correctly. A single client can indeed have multiple sessions, but each session is processed by a single client, until that session is empty (and the timeout has expired).

Also, now understanding your scenario a bit better, it is indeed true that if a client holds a session, it will not give up that session until all the messages have been processed. If it is expected that new clients will regularly be introduced, and sessions are not regularly emptied, it could be beneficial to release the sessions in a specified interval instead.

I got the same conclusion that you said previously. It is needed to write explicit logic that will release sessions based on specific conditions? That's the core of my question. So, Service Bus cannot automatically rebalance sessions and listeners, in a way Kafka does it, but I have to write my own functionality that periodically checks for specific conditions, counts the number of active listeners at a particular moment, and explicitly releases the sessions to trigger rebalancing?

Correct, clients work independently from each other, and so to release a session on a client they would need to implement that themselves.
